# parallel inference in tensorflow (CPUs)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

this is a really basic question, but I can't get the answer anywhere.

Using tensorflow, can I do inference (`tf.keras.Model.predict()`) on multiple CPUs in parallel? I am using `tf.data.Dataset` to represent my data, but from the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict) it seems multiprocessing can be used only with generators or tf.keras.Sequence objects. Why is that? Am I supposed to somehow create an ordinary python generator from the `Dataset` or to manage the parallelism on my own with `multiprocessing` package? What would be the standard way of doing this?

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: I also would like to see this answered.  There is massive confusion on this point due to the transition from Tensorflow 1.x to 2.x which changes the way configuration happens, thus rendering google searches all but worthless.  You are, apparently, using 2.x, correct?

Comment: yes, I am, I added a tf2 tag to make this explicit